# How to develop dynamic multiple tabs in vaadin and spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

As we've seen in almost every browser a feature for multiple browsing tabs. How is it possible for a Web-application dev to develop such a feature? How can I store the user state as it is while navigating through different tabs?

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP session is shared between all browser tabs that point to the same application. In Spring Vaadin app, you can use a `session` scoped Bean to store state that is available to each browser tab.